# Altium Via stitching vs Via Shielding

Tags: pcb, altium

What is the difference between add stitching to net and add shielding to net ?

In my understanding in both case it create via to shield some part of the cricuit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Via shielding](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/PCB_Dlg-AddViaShieldingToNet((Add%20Shielding%20to%20Net))_AD/?help-data=PCB.Cmd.DoViaShielding.PLPCB:ViaShielding) is meant to shield a net (read: a track) from disturbances: Think of an RF signal trace that gets shielding GND vias left and right of it that follow the trace.

[Via stitching](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/PCB_Dlg-AddViaStitchingToNet((Add%20Stitching%20to%20Net))_AD/?help-data=PCB.Cmd.DoViaStitching.PLPCB:ViaStitchingFlood) is meant to connect a signal on one layer with the same signal on another layer. Think of connecting a VCC polygon pour on top with a corresponding power plane. The vias generated for this kind of connection are meant to be evenly distributed over an area (which can be along a line, but doesn't have to be)

Both work similar but via shielding follows a trace without you having to specify the area manually.
Since both add vias of a requested net, you can accomplish similar tasks with them. Its more like a different use case in mind.

Comment: perfect. I was on the case of the RF trace and was confused.